# How best way to resize textfield to fit all text

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield

I got a textField (html text) that is very dynamic, and I have to resize the box to fix it and calculate the space occupied. I'm using...

```
myTextField.height = myTextField.textHeight;
```

But the result is not very precise, even the Adobe description says that is not. There is a better way to do it? There is some "auto resize" propriety of this class? And for the last: what is the purpose of this "textHeight" if it doesn't provide the real text height?

Comment: Since nobody else has an opinion to share, I did chose the answer that is the method I'm using now. Is not perfect, but is enough for me. Maybe someday Adobe will provide something better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`textHeight` returns correct value if you define width. I also add a margin of 4-6, depending on text field's text format, to make sure all my text is displayed. Although it's somewhat crutchy, it didn't fail me with dynamic TFs too, but I only used `text` property, not `htmlText`. About auto-resize - `textHeight` is for this purpose, but there is no actual auto-resize for text fields.

Comment: I'm wondering if the problem is the border line. I left the border in true, so there is a line that maybe take 2 pixels from the text and lead to the error. What is strange is when i begin writing the first line, the bottom of characters are cut out, but the line is there. The second line seams ok, until I do break the paragraph (new p tag). Than the last line don't appears anymore, as I keep writing. What I'm doing is saving the right value of textHeight (I need it to align a photo) and than I add some points to be sure that last line will be displayed.

Comment: I'm unsure, I don't use border on textfields, and it still cuts bottom if setting width to equal `textHeight`.

Comment: As can be seen on san.chez reply image (which is a part of TextLineMetrics official documentation) there are a 2-pixel gutters on left, top, right and bottom sides. Though it looks quite strange that Adobe didn't make a named constant for those gutters size.

Answer (score 7):

TextField class has a [getLineMetrics()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#getLineMetrics%28%29) method which returns [TextLineMetrics](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextLineMetrics.html).

There are nice examples on both pages.

You can get the number of text lines in a multiline text field with [numLines()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#numLines) method.

[image]

Comment: This is only for a line. I need for all text field. I'll add some pixels to not cutting out bottom of text, but I'm sure should be a professional way to deal with.

Answer (score 3):

do this:

```
myTextField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
// if it should not be singleline then add this aswell
myTextField.wordWrap = true;
myTextField.multiline = true;
```

As for your second question:
`textHeight` returns the height of the text in pixels.
check the example in the docs -> [AS3 Docs TextField.textHeight](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#textHeight)

Comment: This will only align text to the left.

Comment: have you tried? If autoSize is set to TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT, the text is treated as left-justified text, meaning that the left margin of the text field remains fixed and any resizing of a single line of the text field is on the right margin. If the text includes a line break (for example, "\n" or "\r"), the bottom is also resized to fit the next line of text.

Comment: I tried, but didn't work. Maybe because I'm working with html and breaks are end - beginning of paragraph tags. Maybe it will work as a trick, but not sure if it is a example to be followed. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

If you want something more precise, I found a solution from looking at [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextLineMetrics.html), and this [tip](http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?442282-number-of-lines-in-a-text-field).

Both of the following work perfectly for me with single-line, multi-line word-wrap (just text wrap, and \n), and multi-line no word wrap (just \n).

Short assumptive version (don't use this):

```
var totalLines = textField.bottomScrollV - textField.scrollV + textField.maxScrollV;
var metrics    = textField.getLineMetrics(0);
var gutter     = 2;
var actualHeight = (metrics.ascent + metrics.descent) * totalLines + (totalLines - 1) * metrics.leading + 2 * gutter;
```

Longer better version where lines have differing metrics (use this):

```
var gutter  = 2;
var totalLines = textField.bottomScrollV - textField.scrollV + textField.maxScrollV;

var actualHeight = 0;
var prevLeading = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < totalLines; i += 1)
{
    var metrics = textField.getLineMetrics(i);
    actualHeight += metrics.ascent + metrics.descent + prevLeading;
    prevLeading = metrics.leading;
}
actualHeight += 2 * gutter;
```

For a single line test with an inline image where textField height gives me 32, textHeight gives me 39, the calculated height (actualHeight above) is 34. For a multi-line test where height is 97.20, textHeight is 23.79, actualHeight is 97.15. This actual height includes the gutter on both sides, but strips out the trailing leading if there is any.